# ORA-01882: timezone region not found ORA-02063: line precediendo a DBLink

Tags: oracle, weblogic, weblogic12c

An error occurred accessing info in DataBase, the database is Oracle. I access the database from a Weblogic 12.

The last time I had the same error with timezone. I fixed using the following (like argument in Weblogic 11):

> -Duser.timezone=GMT

This time I get this error:

```
java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01882: timezone region  not found ORA-02063: line precediendo a DBLink
```

Here is the SQL:

```
SELECT A.DEPT, A.EMP_NAME, A.EMP_LOC, A.LAST_NAME, A.ADDRESS_1, A.ADDRESS_2, A.ADDRESS_3, A.ADDRESS_4, A.CONTROL_NUM, A.EMP_SSID, A.PEN_DATE, B.EMP_LEVEL_ACCESS, C.CONF_NUM, replace(A.EX_SALARY, ' ', '') as EX_SALARY, replace(A.EX_SAL_CODE, ' ', '') as EX_SAL_CODE, replace(A.BIRTHDATE, ' ', '') as BIRTHDATE FROM EMP_W2_INFO_TBL A, EMP_LEVEL_ACCESS_VW B, FILING_CONF_TBL C WHERE A.EMP_NUM = 'XXXXX' AND A.TAX_YEAR = '2016' AND A.EMP_NUM = B.EMP_ID AND A.TAX_YEAR = C.TAX_YEAR (+);
```

I validate DBLink is not corrupted checking the connectiong.

Comment: What is the SQL statement that throws the exception?

Comment: Please edit your question to add that, so it can be formatted properly. The source code for the view might be useful too, as this doesn't seem to have any timestamp/time zone references. How did you validate the link, and what happens if you just query the view directly?

Comment: Also, have you [set that flag for all servers](https://blogs.oracle.com/wlscoherence/entry/time_zone_on_weblogic_server)?

Comment: Of course, I use  "-Duser.timezone=GMT"  command

Comment: OK, what you mean is get the time zone from my web application like in the example.

Comment: Well, I meant it isn't clear from your question when you're setting that flag, so whether it would only apply to the admin server say, and not managed servers. But yes, testing what is actually happening as shown in that blog might be interesting.